# How to nested component to component through UIkit?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to create a mindmap object of mindmap app. The object contains text. So I want to add a label inside the rectangle. How to nest label to rectangle?

I have created two components. The first CGrectangle, the second UIlabel. And I added UIlabel code behind the CGrectangle code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let rect = CGRect(x: 140, y: 350, width: 100, height: 100)
        let myView = UIView(frame: rect)
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
        label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "I'm a test label"

        myView.addSubview(label)
        self.view.addSubview(myView)
    }
}
```

The position of the added UIlabel moves down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position you give the label needs to be relative to its parent view which is `myView`. `myView` is 100x100 so the label's center needs to be 50, 50. And the label's width is twice the size of the rectangle. That's not a good idea.

Comment: If the position value is higher than the parent element, you have noticed that the position value is not adjusted according to the position value. thank you!